# update or insert table with all records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm importing data from one database table to another with different structure and I'm using this code:

```
UPDATE BD1.dbo.Table1 
SET C2=t2.C2 
from BD2.dbo.Table2 as t2 
WHERE c1=t2.c1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI 
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO  BD1.dbo.Table1 (c1,c2) 
select t2.c1, t2.c2 From BD2.dbo.Table2 as t2
```

If I don't have any matches between BD1 and BD2 this works fine, but if I do, the command just updates the existing fields. I want to update the existing fields and create the new ones (?!).
I believe the problem is in the @@rowcount=0, but I have a where condition before it should respect record by record, doesn't it?

Comment: You might want to do, `insert into table1 Select * from table2` to handle the inserts. This will insert every record from table2 into table1 granted the column definitions match

Comment: I can't do that the structure between tables are different.

Comment: is there some reason you need to do this only in one statement? it might be cleaner and easier to split it up into one update for existing records and an insert for new records

Comment: Yes I need to do this in one statement.

Comment: you might consider using MERGE to handle the update on matched, insert where not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge statement was written for just this operation.  It is called an UPSERT = update the record if it exists or insert it if it does not.

Since, I do not have your schema, I can not test the snippet below.  But here is a TSQL sample that might work for you.

```
-- UPSERT from staging to production
MERGE INTO 
    BD1.dbo.Table1 AS Target
USING 
    (SELECT C1, C2 FROM BD2.dbo.Table2) AS Source (C1, C2)
ON 
    Target.C1 = Source.C1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.C2 = Source.C2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (C1, C2) VALUES (Source.C1, Source.C2)
;
```